# AngularJS SlimPHP CRUD - $http.delete не работает - XMLHttpRequest cannot load

Tags: php, .htaccess, angularjs, crud, slim

Проблема с созданием CRUD с использованием AngularJS и SlimPHP v3. Все работает для $app->get и $app->post но получаю ошибку для $app->delete.

Фронт и бек поставил на разных доменах, потому-что для работы Slim надо было настроить htaccess так, чтобы все запросы перекидывал на index.php, поэтому мне не удалось поставить фронт и бек на один сервер так чтобы запросы осуществлялись.

Вот мой бекенд index.php

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
$app = new \Slim\App();

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');


$app->options('/test', function() use($app) {
    $response = $app->response();
    $app->response()->status(200);
    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); 
    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, X-Requested-With, X-authentication, X-client');
    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
});


$app->get('/test/', function(Slim\Http\Request $request, Slim\Http\Response $response, array $args) {

    $id = $args['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_osoft_orders";

    $dbhost = "host";
    $dbuser = "user";
    $dbpass = "pass";
    $dbname = "db";

    $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

    $headers = $response->getHeaders();
    $response = $response->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json'); 
    $response = $response->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    $headers = $response->getHeaders();

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $conn->set_charset("utf8");
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $resultsArray = array();
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            array_push($resultsArray, $row);
        }
        $response->write(json_encode($resultsArray));
    }
    else {
        $response->write("0 results");
    }
    $conn->close();
});
$app->delete('/test/{id}', function(Slim\Http\Request $request, Slim\Http\Response $response, array $args) {

    $response = $response->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    $response->write("delete is OK");
});
    $app->run();
?>
```

А вот фронт на Angular:

```
function getOrders(){
    $http.get("http://mydomain.com/test/").success(function(data){
        $scope.orders = data;
    });

};

getOrders();
$scope.deleteOrder = function (orderId) {
    console.log("order to delete id: " + orderId);
    $http.delete("http://mydomain.com/test/"+orderId).success(function(response){
        console.log('delete response: ' + response);
    });
    getOrders();
};
```

Order Id в console.log В Angular получаю правильный, но потом 2 ошибки:

DELETE http://mydomain.com/test/22 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://mydomain.com/test/22. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://mydomain.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

Спасибо за помошь.

Comment: пожалуйста, переведите вопрос на русский язык. это можно сделать, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что здесь вопросы задают на русском языке.